# Migration from Jboss 5.1 to Wildfly 11

Tags: migration, jboss5.x, wildfly-11

Need help to migrate the application from Jboss 5 to wildfly 11

Application is 5 year old developed on Struts 2.x framework and Database Oracle12C, java 1.8
It is not Maven based application, all the jar files are managed in Jboss server folder "jboss 5.1.0\server\default\lib\" and we have EAR

We are truing to migrate to wildfly 11 and running into lot of issues,
Jars were not so easy to migrate to wildfly so dumped all the jars into application and managed to resolve most of the dependence issues in appliccation, however we are not making any progress there after

Data-source is configured in standalone.xml 
jboss-web.xml was throwing error at a particular line where  tag was - removed it

I am running into below error w.r.t deployment of war

```
12:45:40,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "ecommerce.war" (runtime-name: "ecommerce.war")
12:45:45,244 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry log4j.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,256 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry log4j-core.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,265 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry logkit-1.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,266 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,266 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry concurrent-1.3.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,266 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry antlr-2.7.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,287 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry messages.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/o4glrt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,287 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry schema.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/o4glrt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,288 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry ext/sslj.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/o4glrt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,288 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry ext/certj.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/o4glrt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,288 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry ext/cryptoj.jar in /D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ecommerce.war/WEB-INF/lib/o4glrt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:45,954 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ecommerce.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ecommerce.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ecommerce.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener from [Module "deployment.ecommerce.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsComponentDeployer.deploy(JaxrsComponentDeployer.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener from [Module "deployment.ecommerce.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsComponentDeployer.deploy(JaxrsComponentDeployer.java:87)
    ... 6 more

12:45:45,965 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ecommerce.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"ecommerce.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener from [Module \"deployment.ecommerce.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener from [Module \"deployment.ecommerce.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
12:45:45,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "ecommerce.war" with deployment "ecommerce.war"
12:45:45,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ecommerce.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ecommerce.war"
```

Below are application dependent libs from Jboss 5.1.0

```
03-04-2015  03:06 AM           443,432 antlr-2.7.6.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM           167,735 antlr-runtime-3.5.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM            30,651 apache-jakarta-commons-email.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM         1,853,274 apache-solr-core-4.0.0-BETA.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM           362,101 apache-solr-solrj-4.0.0-BETA.jar
14-01-2015  12:42 PM         1,486,109 appengine-awt-1.0.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM            43,578 asm-3.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM            38,275 asm-commons-3.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM            21,503 asm-tree-3.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM            73,734 avalon-framework.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM            33,506 axis-ant.jar
02-03-2015  12:15 PM         1,599,570 axis.jar
03-07-2015  07:26 PM           236,415 bronto-api-client-1.0.3.jar
03-07-2015  07:26 PM           109,135 bronto-api-sdk-1.0.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:12 PM           231,320 commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM            91,699 commons-chain-1.2.jar
02-09-2012  02:34 PM            41,123 commons-cli-1.2.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           362,252 commons-codec-1.4-javadoc.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM            81,359 commons-codec-1.4-sources.jar
19-10-2014  09:24 PM           263,965 commons-codec-1.9.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           559,366 commons-collections-3.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           558,376 commons-collections.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           148,783 commons-digester-2.0.jar
02-03-2015  12:15 PM            71,442 commons-discovery-0.2.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM            32,321 commons-email-1.2.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM            68,622 commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           305,001 commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           214,796 commons-httpclient.jar
10-07-2014  08:11 PM           173,587 commons-io-2.2.jar
19-03-2014  01:15 PM           261,809 commons-lang-2.4.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM           315,805 commons-lang3-3.1.jar
15-10-2014  02:08 PM            61,829 commons-logging-1.2.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM            44,598 commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM            22,327 commons-logging-api.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM            91,184 commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM           138,956 commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM            56,404 cos.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM           456,913 dom4j-1.1.jar
01-04-2015  06:44 PM           239,475 dozer-5.3.2.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM         1,631,207 drools-compiler-6.2.0.CR3.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM         3,405,305 drools-core-6.2.0.CR3.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM            77,826 ezmorph-1.0.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM            86,463 ezmorph.jar
30-03-2015  11:45 AM           477,864 facebook4j-core-2.2.1.jar
27-04-2018  12:59 PM                 0 files.txt
24-03-2015  04:44 PM            30,817 fluent-hc-4.4.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:10 PM           931,168 freemarker-2.3.19.jar
04-04-2015  05:15 AM           210,856 gson-2.3.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:09 PM            60,962 hibernate-jbosscache2.jar
16-05-2015  06:34 PM           157,516 httpasyncclient-4.0.1.jar
16-04-2015  05:06 PM           176,931 httpasyncclient-4.1.jar
16-04-2015  05:07 PM            34,947 httpasyncclient-cache-4.1.jar
24-03-2015  04:43 PM           720,931 httpclient-4.4.1.jar
24-03-2015  04:45 PM           158,974 httpclient-cache-4.4.1.jar
24-03-2015  04:45 PM            17,360 httpclient-win-4.4.1.jar
14-03-2015  05:29 PM           322,234 httpcore-4.4.1.jar
14-03-2015  05:34 PM            31,376 httpcore-ab-4.4.1.jar
14-03-2015  05:32 PM           355,702 httpcore-nio-4.4.1.jar
24-03-2015  04:44 PM            40,631 httpmime-4.4.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:09 PM         2,635,543 infor-sx.jar
10-07-2014  08:09 PM         2,783,313 InforSx.jar
10-07-2014  08:08 PM           621,146 jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:08 PM         4,720,327 jacorb.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM           136,217 java-unrar-0.5.jar
14-11-2016  04:16 PM         1,135,117 javamelody.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM           544,021 javassist-3.7.ga.jar
11-04-2014  11:55 AM           136,069 jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.6.5.1.jar
02-03-2015  12:15 PM            31,191 jaxrpc.jar
27-10-2013  05:10 PM            64,919 jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.1.final-sources.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM         1,164,438 jbosscache-core.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM           192,849 jbosscache-pojo.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM            15,910 jbossweb-extras.jar
22-05-2009  11:03 AM            30,308 jbossws-native-jaxrpc.jar
22-05-2009  11:03 AM            20,978 jbossws-native-jaxws-ext.jar
22-05-2009  11:03 AM            48,991 jbossws-native-jaxws.jar
22-05-2009  11:03 AM            28,065 jbossws-native-saaj.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM           349,572 jcaptcha-1.0-all.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM           204,116 jcaptcha-2.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM             6,190 jcaptcha-api-1.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM            10,329 jcaptcha-integration-simple-servlet-2.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
10-07-2014  08:07 PM             2,561 jcip-annotations.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM            85,237 jdom.jar
30-04-2014  05:07 PM         1,527,762 jersey-bundle-1.18.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM         2,071,429 jgroups.jar
13-06-2014  01:58 PM           914,597 jna-4.1.0.jar
13-06-2014  01:58 PM         1,464,423 jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM            98,496 jndi-1.2.1.jar
11-08-2014  04:53 PM           534,827 joda-time-1.6.jar
14-11-2016  04:16 PM           238,016 jrobin-1.5.9.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM           124,932 json-lib-2.1-jdk15.jar
30-04-2014  05:03 PM            46,367 jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM           420,548 jstl.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM           195,159 junit.jar
10-07-2014  08:06 PM           535,221 jxl-2.4.3.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM           143,266 kie-api-6.2.0.CR3.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM           268,137 kie-internal-6.2.0.CR3.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM           317,507 knowledge-api-6.2.0.CR3.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM           352,668 log4j-1.2.8.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM           133,531 log4j-api-2.1.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM           824,749 log4j-core-2.1.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM            22,542 log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM            15,143 log4j-snmp-appender.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM            23,607 log4j-web-2.1.jar
06-08-2015  07:37 PM           355,753 log4j.jar
10-07-2014  08:05 PM           494,975 mail.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM         1,012,100 mvel2-2.2.2.Final.jar
10-07-2014  08:05 PM           827,942 mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
30-10-2014  11:24 PM           994,181 o4glrt.jar
10-07-2014  08:05 PM           227,997 ognl-3.0.6.jar
18-11-2016  04:19 PM         3,397,734 ojdbc7.jar
18-11-2016  04:19 PM         1,659,576 orai18n.jar
10-07-2014  08:05 PM         1,539,291 poi-3.6-20091214.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM         1,820,323 poi-3.8-20120326.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM         1,732,678 poi-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM           300,235 poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM           271,138 poi-examples-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM            30,446 poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM            30,436 poi-excelant-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
10-07-2014  08:04 PM           412,783 poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar
10-07-2014  08:03 PM           933,010 poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
10-07-2014  08:03 PM           568,368 poi-ooxml-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
10-07-2014  08:03 PM         3,774,332 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar
10-07-2014  08:03 PM         4,706,775 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
10-07-2014  08:02 PM         4,185,782 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
10-07-2014  08:01 PM         1,186,887 poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar
10-07-2014  08:01 PM           901,861 poi-scratchpad-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
03-04-2015  03:06 AM           533,455 protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM         1,001,457 sax.jar
14-01-2015  12:42 PM           444,967 sfntly-1.0.0.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            45,277 signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            25,496 slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM             7,669 slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM           329,441 struts-core-1.3.10.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            67,304 struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.16.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM           807,290 struts2-core-2.3.16.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            71,176 struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            32,985 struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.16.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            21,866 struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.16.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            43,312 SuperCSV-1.30.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM             2,638 thputils.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            17,026 tiles-api-2.0.6.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM           128,136 tiles-core-2.0.6.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM            41,587 tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar
30-03-2015  11:45 AM           280,471 twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar
20-10-2014  06:41 PM            30,557 unilogfeed-client-1.0.3.jar
10-07-2014  08:00 PM           177,497 urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar
10-07-2014  07:59 PM           421,246 velocity-1.6.3.jar
10-07-2014  07:59 PM           134,881 velocity-tools-1.3.jar
10-07-2014  07:59 PM           346,580 velocity-tools-2.0.jar
02-03-2015  12:15 PM           168,203 wsdl4j.jar
10-07-2014  07:59 PM         2,666,695 xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
10-07-2014  07:58 PM           115,553 xmlpull-xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
10-07-2014  07:58 PM           481,672 xstream-1.4.2.jar
10-07-2014  07:58 PM           653,404 xwork-core-2.3.16.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd move to the latest of version WildFly 12.0.0.Final, not that much different from 11.

WildFly 7 was a major upgrade/change of architecture with the introduction of the concept of "modules" to store external JARs. Such as Oracle in your case.

I assume you are using EJBs? Which version of?

I have done quite a few migrations from JBoss 4 & 6 (never 5, it was short lived and we skipped it).

I would always deploy as an EAR.

Java EJBs/POJOs etc in the JAR.
GUI/Front-end  (XHTML) in the WAR. 
Packaged together (JAR & WAR) as an EAR.

Personally, I use the EE8 standard of JSF (2.3) as XHTML Facelets and replace Struts with JSF. Have the XHTML communicate with a controller (POJO, annotated as @Model) which in turn calls the EJBs.

> Data-source is configured in standalone.xml jboss-web.xml was throwing
>   error at a particular line where tag was - removed it

Are you starting WildFly with the 'standalone.xml'

```
 ./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml
```

Your error:

> all the jar files are managed in Jboss server folder "jboss
>   5.1.0\server\default\lib\"

No longer "works", have to use the modules for JARs to be loaded at start-up by the Class loader.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener from [Module
>   "deployment.ecommerce.war" from Service Module Loader]

Looks like the log4j JAR is missing in the module, somewhere like this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/12.0.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/log4j/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a dependency issue.

Wildfly system is configured as an enterprise server. This imply that a lot of libraries are already build, optimized and configured.As all is tested and you should use the libraries from server, some time you need to tell the server if you should use some sub-system on your won terms.

For your case, logging sub-system is having a problem and should be solved like this:
configure jboss-deployment-structure.xml 
here is example for log4j

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

I hope this helps.